# In which object Article contents stores?

Tags: apex, community, data-loader

[image: In salesforce, in which object the article content Saves? When i exporting the article from dataloader the content is coming. only fields are coming.]
In salesforce, in which object, article content stores. when i am extracting KnowledgeArticleVersion, there is no content. only some fields are there. i have posted both snapshots.
please help me, i am new in salesforce.
[image: The csv file picture also uploaded here.]

Comment: can you try this SELECT Title , Summary 
FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion, I tried in my org but no use it may be because of some config issues. if this works from your end let me know. by editing you question.

Comment: Yes, tried  SELECT Title , Summary FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion, and   i get summary fields blank.

Comment: After going through the Articles documentation on salesforce I suspected this KnowledgeArticleVersion might contain the field of Article